# Does my website lose its data after VM Instance shutdown?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I need to upgrade my memory in Google cloud instance. So for that, I have to stop my instance. So will I lose my website data? I mean after starting vm instance will my website will come back or not? The same as what is before.

Answer (score 0):

There are some options but depends on the way that you configured your instance. Some options will depend, for example, if you are using a VM with Solid Disk, Local Disk or not, etc.

For this reason, I would recommend you to take a look at this other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31312085/how-to-change-machine-type-of-gce-instance/31329034#31329034). There, it's provided the steps on how to achieve the reboot.

Another option is to check the documentation [Changing the Machine Type of a Stopped Instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance), that provides more information, on how to achieve that.

Let me know if the information helped you!