# Restore postgres data on GCloud VM instance restart

Tags: postgresql, docker, google-compute-engine

We use Postgres as a docker container, and each time we restart the machine, the data and tables are lost.
Even data files under the base and global folders.

Even more, now we've faced some RAM problems, so I'm not able to connect to Postgres and VM instance itself in now way -- neither by ssh, psql client nor redash. The last one says the following:

> Error running query: could not send SSL negotiation packet: Resource temporarily unavailable.

Is there any way to somehow solve the problem?

UPD. I've tried to create a disk snapshot, but it doesn't help.

UPD2. BTW, the pgdata folder is set to be a container volume and could be used outside of it.

Comment: I need more information to better understand the issue. What OS are you using? Are you using a Preemptible Machine? Can you be more specific in regards to your RAM
issue (e.g are they running out?)

Comment: @Milad 1. We use Ubuntu 18.04 and postgres-11.3-apline as base image for the container. 2. No, it's not a Preemptible Machine. 3. You guess it, we ran out of it

Comment: If the machine is continuously running out of memory, then I would suggest
to create a new VM instance with higher memory. There's a thread about this that could help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31312085/how-to-change-machine-type-of-gce-instance